# ES6 generator and the JavaScript heap out of memory error

Tags: ecmascript-6, out-of-memory, generator

Here is my node script:

```
const Q = [];
const Q_LEN = 10;

function* produce() {
    while (Q.length < Q_LEN) {
        const item = Date.now();
        Q.push(item);
        console.log(`Item ${item} is produced`);

        if (Q.length === Q_LEN) {
            yield;
        }
    }
}

function* consume() {
    while (Q.length > 0) {
        const item = Q.pop();
        console.log(`Item ${item} is consumed`);

        if (Q.length === 0) {
            yield;
        }
    }
}

function bootstrap() {
    const producer = produce();
    const consumer = consume();

    while(true) {
        producer.next();
        consumer.next();
    }
}

bootstrap();
```

I want the producer and consumer keep running forever. But after a while the script is halted and node reports the following error:

**FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**

I tried the option "--max-old-space-size=4096". The script is halted at the end but seems running longer than it does without the option. So I want to know whether there is a memory leak in this script and why the error occurs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your running this in a while loop.

Comment: The only memory leak I can see is that you are synchronously rammed full with messages, though I thought it would cope with that. Does it run longer if you remove the `console.log` statements, or log only single characters?

Comment: @Bergi, thank you very much. I learned why console.log causes the out of memory error in the https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3524 post. And I also changed my implementation in another way